# Replace selected text on [shift insert] is broken in emacs 25.1

Tags: terminal-emacs, delete-selection-mode

I updated to 25.1 and found that copy/paste works differently.

For example when I select a word "**visit**" and try to replace this word with [shift insert], **text** in clipboard is inserted in the beginning of the selection, instead of replacing it.

[image]

When I select **visit** and type text, **visit** is replaced as expected.

I have enabled delete selection and transient mark modes, it worked well in 24.5.

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Works for me on Emacs 25.1 started with `emacs -q -nw` in gnome-terminal on RHEL 7.

Comment: From the sound of it, there might be a bug. Try to provide a step-by-step recipe, starting with `emacs -Q`, and send it to `M-x report-emacs-bug`. (If you cannot come up with such a recipe from `emacs -Q` then bisect your init file to find out what is causing the problem.)

Comment: Thanks. I run CentOS 7.2. Has just deleted old emacs, support folder, and init file. Downloaded sources and made emacs from a scratch. Insert still does not replace text. Will try to report bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a fix for the problem on [emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Comments_on_CopyAndPaste)

```
(setq x-select-enable-primary t)
(setq select-enable-primary t)
(setq mouse-drag-copy-region t)
```

> **Quick tip**: if you’re here looking to fix the fact that in Emacs shift-insert no longer pastes that text you highlighted with the mouse in your browser, the 2014 answer is to set **x-select-enable-primary** to true, and set **mouse-drag-copy-region** to true to go the other way - I can’t imagine why this excellent default was changed but it’s very hard to find the answer in the verbiage below.

But this works only for emacs installed from sources [github/emacs-mirror](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/archive/master.zip), not 25.1

I also found that it depends on terminal. xterm fails, while vt100 works good

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found `(setq select-enable-primary t)` makes the situation.  I have sent it to `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Setting `select-enable-primary` to `nil` fixes a problem for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you! It seems that I placed the expression without understanding what `select-enable-primary` does.

Answer (score 0):

I just put  `(delete-selection-mode 1)`  in my .spacemacs file but I'm sure you can also put it in init.el

Source: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeleteSelectionMode

Then saved <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> and reloaded/refreshed, on spacemacs that's `SPC f e R`  there are many other ways to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580650/how-can-i-reload-emacs-after-changing-it has a long and interesting (to me) discussion, I think <kbd>M-:</kbd> would be my favorite answer however it wasn't working for me so I went with my tried and true `SPC f e R`

Interesting fact: with this delete-selection-mode, to undo, takes 2 actions! I have to <kbd>C-/</kbd> twice to get my original text back.

Very interesting: once you set `(delete-selection-mode 1)` if you just delete that line in the config and reload, the setting will still be there, you have to `(delete-selection-mode 0)` to recreate the original behavior.